# Shortcut of watch window in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm C++ user, and I like to use watch window.

Everytime I want to investigate variables

I do it in watch window pannel..

Before vs2008 the shortcut was ALT+3.

really easy to press.

But with vs2012, 
I must press CTRL+ALT+W, 1
I think this is really ugly.
hard to press, multiple step...

But I don't want to change default setting,
because I have many environment and 
I don't want to configure the key setting
every time I move or change computer.

Is there any good way or
easy way to debug with out pressing that CTRL+ALT+W, 1 commend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the change to the shortcut key/keys, then you could export the settings.

Tools > Import and Export Settings Wizard. Exports into a file you can send to yourself etc.

Then you could import the settings you like into other visual studio environments you have ;).

Answer (score 1):

To change it back to Alt+3

- Select Tools/Options
- Goto Environment/Keyboard
- In the list of commands, scroll down to **Debug.Watch1**

It will tell you that the shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+W,1

In **Press Shortcut keys** box, press Alt+3